# Itunes Enterprise Partner Feed (EPF) directory structure

Tags: itunes, feed, epf

I'm trying to create a script to download the most recent feed information file (e.g. video.tbz) but there does not seem to be a pattern for the directory structure. Basically how can I get the most recent incremental feed file?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is no structure. You have to iterate thorugh possible dates.
You can do it with wget or curl and just check if you get a http 200.